# recursive function in arm assembly language

Tags: assembly, arm

```
    .text
    .global main
main:
    sub sp,sp,#4
    str lr,[sp,#0]

    @ compiling a recursive C procdure
    @ int fact(int n){
    @   if(n < 1){
    @       return 1;
    @   }else{
    @       return (n * fact(n-1));
    @   }
    @ }

    @ put n in r0


    mov r0,#6   
fact:   
    sub sp,sp,#8
    str lr,[sp,#8]
    str r0,[sp,#0]

    cmp r0,#1
    bge L1

    mov r0,#1
    add sp,sp,#8
    mov pc,lr


L1:
    sub r0,r0,#1
    bl fact

    mov r12,r0
    ldr r0,[sp,#0]  
    ldr lr,[sp,#0]
    add sp,sp,#8

    mul r0,r12,r0
    mov pc,lr

    mov r7,r0


    ldr r0, =format
    mov r1,r7
    bl printf

    ldr lr,[sp,#0]
    add sp,sp,#4
    mov pc,lr


    .data
format: .asciz "The Answer is %d\n"
```

I have wrote a code in arm assembly language to find the factorial of an integer.
But this code do not print any anwser. I could not find why it is.

Comment: So what *does* happen?  Does it get stuck in an infinite loop?  Use a debugger. 
 And add details to make this a [mcve]

Comment: Add some comments to the code. Explain why you are manipulating the stack directly instead of using push and pop.

Answer (score 1):

The comments from [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) and [Elliot Alderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9830341/elliot-alderson) about needing to provide a MCV example and needing to comment your code are absolutely right.  Please respond to requests like this because they make it much easier to help you.

Your most obvious error is on the fifth line following the `L1` label: your offset address for reloading `lr` is incorrect (you're popping the pushed value of `r0` twice).

There are several weird features of your code though which you should really address.  The first of these would have prevented the error above:

- Use `STMFD` and `LDMFD` to push and pop.  It is faster and less error-prone than using manual manipulation of the stack pointer.  If `sp` contains your stack pointer (as is usual) you can use the synonyms `PUSH` and `POP` instead.  For example, the three lines where the error is located could have been written simply as

  ```
  LDMFD sp!, {r0,lr}
  ```

  or

  ```
  POP {r0,lr}
  ```

  Note also that you can return by popping the stored value of `lr` directly into `pc` rather than popping it into `lr` and issuing a `bx lr` (this is known as an 'implicit return' and saves a line of code).
- The [ARM Application Binary Interface](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html) dictates that functions are responsible for preserving the contents of `r4-r11`, `lr` and `sp`.  `sp` is preserved if your use of the stack is balanced of course.  You are not doing this.  Also because `r0-r3` and `r12` are not guaranteed to be preserved across calls, it is generally a good idea to avoid using these for local scratch storage.
- The ABI also specifies that the stack should be 8-byte aligned across function calls in different translation units, so it is a good idea to retain 8-byte alignment at all times by always pushing and popping even numbers of registers.  There is no performance penalty for this.
- It would be good practice stylistically to separate `fact` from `main`, rather than nesting one inside the other as you have done.  (You would be forced to make this separation in a high-level language, including in C.)
- Using a signed type for your argument is a strange idea when you ignore negative arguments anyway.  `bge` uses a 'signed greater or equal' comparison; `bhs` is the unsigned equivalent.  You could actually use `bhi` ('unsigned higher') because if the argument is 1 then there is no point in computing its factorial.

I have rewritten your code to follow these guidelines, as below.  I have not added comments, that's for you to do.  I have also not modified the logic of your algorithm, so there may be room for improvement there.  I also haven't tested it!

```
    .text
    .global main
main:
    stmfd sp!, {r7,lr}

    @ compiling a recursive C procedure
    @ unsigned int fact(unsigned int n){
    @   if(n < 1){
    @       return 1;
    @   }else{
    @       return (n * fact(n-1));
    @   }
    @ }

    stmfd sp!, {r7,lr}

    @ put n in r0
    mov r0,#6

    bl fact

    mov r1,r0
    ldr r0, =format
    bl printf

    ldmfd sp!, {r7,pc}


fact:
    stmfd sp!, {r7,lr}

    cmp r0,#1
    bhi L1

    mov r0,#1
    ldmfd sp!, {r7,pc}
L1:
    mov r7,r0
    sub r0,r0,#1
    bl fact

    mov r7,r0
    mul r0,r0,r7

    ldmfd sp!, {r7,pc}


    .data
format: .asciz "The Answer is %d\n"
```